# Polymer focus() has to be wrapped in setTimeout() to work?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

When trying to give focus to a polymer element I've always have to wrap it in a setTimout, in this case it's a polymer `paper-input` element. Like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   paperInput.focus(); 
}, 10);
```

I've read different Stackoverflow posts on the subject focus() polymer elements and I've seen that some of them have the same problem. 
I really can't accept the fact that it just works when I wrap it I want to know why it dose not work when I don't wrap it.

So my question is, why? Why do I have to wrap it in a `setTimeout`?

Using Polymer 1.4 at the moment. But I've noticed the same behaviour in older versions.

Thanks!

**Update**

I've tried to reproduce the problem, but this actually works. So i'll bet the problem is in my own environment: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tutujufane/edit?html,css,js,output)

I will keep this post updated if I find a solution to my problem.
thanks for the help.

Comment: Interesting question but without seeing where in your application this code is and what the component looks like that contains the `paper-input` it's quite hard to tell. Can you create a Plunker to reproduce?

Comment: Hmm, I will see if I can reproduce this in a Plunker. Will hopefully post it in a update of this post later today.

Comment: In my tests with Polymer 1.4.0, `setTimeout` is not needed to use `focus()`. I agree that we'll need to see your code to help with your bug. Can you update your question to include links to the SO posts?

Comment: @JonathanAndersson I was able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @tony19 AAA thanks. Did not have the time to do it yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the simple case, where no other elements are on the page except `<paper-input>`, there seems to be no problem with `focus()`.

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.4.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
</head>
<body>
  <paper-input></paper-input>
  <paper-input></paper-input>
  <paper-input id="my-input"></paper-input>
  <paper-input></paper-input>

  <script>
    HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
      document.getElementById('my-input').focus();
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

<sup>[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/bavigo/edit?html,output)</sup>

But I can reproduce the problem in a slightly more complex case where `<paper-input>` is inside `<iron-pages>`. In the following example, the third `<paper-input>` on Page 2 should have been focused.

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.4.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-tabs/paper-tab.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <paper-tabs selected={{selected}}>
        <paper-tab>PAGE 1</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>PAGE 2</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>PAGE 3</paper-tab>
      </paper-tabs>
      <iron-pages selected=[[selected]]>
        <section>
          <h3>empty page 1</h3>
        </section>
        <section>
          <h3>page 2 inputs</h3>
          <paper-input></paper-input>
          <paper-input></paper-input>
          <paper-input id="my-input"></paper-input>
          <paper-input></paper-input>
        </section>
        <section>
          <h3>empty page 3</h3>
        </section>
      </iron-pages>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-foo',
        properties: {
          selected: {
            type: Number,
            value: function() { return 1; }
          }
        },
        ready: function() {
          this.$['my-input'].focus();
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/rojalac/edit?html,output)</sup>

If I use your workaround of wrapping the `focus()` call with `setTimeout()` (which effectively defers the work until the end of the execution queue), the focus correctly occurs:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  this.$['my-input'].focus();
}.bind(this), 0);
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.4.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-tabs/paper-tab.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <paper-tabs selected={{selected}}>
        <paper-tab>PAGE 1</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>PAGE 2</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>PAGE 3</paper-tab>
      </paper-tabs>
      <iron-pages selected=[[selected]]>
        <section>
          <h3>empty page 1</h3>
        </section>
        <section>
          <h3>page 2 inputs</h3>
          <paper-input></paper-input>
          <paper-input></paper-input>
          <paper-input id="my-input"></paper-input>
          <paper-input></paper-input>
        </section>
        <section>
          <h3>empty page 3</h3>
        </section>
      </iron-pages>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-foo',
        properties: {
          selected: {
            type: Number,
            value: function() { return 1; }
          }
        },
        ready: function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            this.$['my-input'].focus();
          }.bind(this), 0);
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tavabo/edit?html,output)</sup>

This implies to me that `<paper-input>` is not actually ready when we try to focus it (despite being inside this custom element's `ready` callback), and I'm not sure whether that's a bug. To workaround the issue, we could set an event handler for `WebComponentsReady` that would be called when all components in the system have fully initialized:

```
document.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
   this.$['my-input'].focus();
}.bind(this));
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.4.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-tabs/paper-tab.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-pages/iron-pages.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <paper-tabs selected={{selected}}>
        <paper-tab>PAGE 1</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>PAGE 2</paper-tab>
        <paper-tab>PAGE 3</paper-tab>
      </paper-tabs>
      <iron-pages selected=[[selected]]>
        <section>
          <h3>empty page 1</h3>
        </section>
        <section>
          <h3>page 2 inputs</h3>
          <paper-input></paper-input>
          <paper-input></paper-input>
          <paper-input id="my-input"></paper-input>
          <paper-input></paper-input>
        </section>
        <section>
          <h3>empty page 3</h3>
        </section>
      </iron-pages>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-foo',
        properties: {
          selected: {
            type: Number,
            value: function() { return 1; }
          }
        },
        ready: function() {
          document.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
            this.$['my-input'].focus();
          }.bind(this));
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/catubis/edit?html,output)</sup>

I think the `WebComponentsReady` event handler is better than `setTimeout` because I don't think it's safe to assume that `WebComponentsReady` always occurs at the end of this execution queue. `setTimeout` probably only works by chance.

Comment: Actually if you change `this.$['my-input'].focus();` to `this.$['my-input'].$.input.focus();`, the input will correctly be focused on. You just have to call the focus() method directly in the `input`

Comment: @LoveAndHappiness That still doesn't work in this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/bugado/edit?html,output)

Comment: Nice snippets @tony19 My problem is not in the ready callback. The problem occures when all components are ready and the user press a button to switch focus to the paper-input.  [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tutujufane/edit?html,css,js,output)

This dose work. So I'm having a hard time reproducing it.
(Press B when in the contenteditable to switch focus)